# Simplify resolutions in media queries

Tags: html, media-queries, html5-video

I just was thinking about how one would go about providing a video in different intrinsic sizes for browsers on modern devices.

[Using the media attribute with `<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#using_the_media_attribute_with_video) describes a simple use case, that uses a larger version of the video on bigger viewport sizes:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo-large.webm" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <source src="foo.webm">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML video.
</video>
```

But since [media queries use CSS pixels in the `with` feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width), one would need to manually take high resolution displays into account, if the video should look crisp.

```
<source src="foo-large.webm" media="(min-width: 800px),
  ((min-width: 400px) and (min-resolution: 2x)">
```

The times when the [Retina Display](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display) was the top resolution are long gone, and we find ourselves with a spectre of resolutions on displays today, currently up to 5K.

So to reliably provide a size of video to most devices that can profit from it, one would end up with a really long list:

```
<source src="foo-large.webm" media="(min-width: 800px),
  ((min-width: 533px) and (min-resolution: 1.5x),
  ((min-width: 400px) and (min-resolution: 2x),
  ((min-width: 300px) and (min-resolution: 3x),
  ((min-width: 200px) and (min-resolution: 4x)
  …">
```

For images, one can use a [combination of `srcset` and `sizes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes), to have the browser figure out the right size based on resolution and even connection quality. But these attributes are not valid for videos.

Is there any simpler way to reference a larger video without listing all kinds of resolutions? Is there something in the works?

With this use case in mind it seems very surprising that there is no media feature querying the actual device pixels on the viewport. Or is there?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: ok I removed them. It was a copy from MDN.

Comment: MDN uses Prettier to format their code. [It's caused much consternation for this very reason](https://github.com/orgs/mdn/discussions/242) but they've decided to live with it for now.